# Generating code coverage report in Clover XML format ... syntax error

Tags: laravel, phpunit, php-code-coverage

I'm using phpstorm and wrote some test in my laravel app. The `phpunit.xml` is alsmost default.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <coverage processUncoveredFiles="true">
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </include>
    </coverage>
    <php>
        <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
        <server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
        <server name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
        <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

At the end of my thest I get the following error:

```
Time: 00:15.742, Memory: 58.00 MB

OK (26 tests, 69 assertions)

Generating code coverage report in Clover XML format ... syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting '{'

Process finished with exit code 2
```

I've no idea where I shall start to look at. Appreciate any help!

### Update:

same issue by trying to generate html report

```
❯ .\vendor\bin\phpunit --coverage-html ./coverage.html
PHPUnit 9.5.5 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

............................                                      28 / 28 (100%)

Time: 00:23.702, Memory: 74.00 MB

OK (28 tests, 125 assertions)

Generating code coverage report in HTML format ... syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting '{'
```

### Update 2:

Run reduced minimal reproducing test case:

```php
class MinimalTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic feature test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function test_example()
    {
        $response = $this->get('https://google.com');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

`❯ .\vendor\bin\phpunit --filter MinimalTest --coverage-html ./coverage.html`

```
❯ .\vendor\bin\phpunit --debug --filter MinimalTest --coverage-html ./coverage.html
PHPUnit 9.5.5 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 7.4.16 with Xdebug 3.0.4
Configuration: C:\Users\***\localGit\xampp\htdocs\oneup\app\phpunit.xml

Test 'Tests\Feature\MinimalTest::test_example' started
Test 'Tests\Feature\MinimalTest::test_example' ended


Time: 00:01.242, Memory: 42.00 MB

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)

Generating code coverage report in HTML format ... syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting '{'
```

Comment: this looks like as if one of your files - at least - has a syntax error. take the time and check all of them for syntax errors, study your directory layout, the php version and related configuration. additional tooling might distract you from your studies: https://github.com/php-parallel-lint/PHP-Parallel-Lint

Comment: @hakre, thanks for your replay. I've run other  [reduced to a minimum test](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage/issues/858#issuecomment-870463210) with the same issue. Testing works fine, its just the coverage report that fail. However, I'll try `PHP-Parallel-Lint`. Thanks for now!

Comment: The error is perhaps happening during code-coverage data processing, so you can (temporarily) disable that to find out if it is the cause. Then you would know that. Enable it again to provoke the error again. Also check `--verbose` flag next to `--debug` (hopefully it helps).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the issue. I isolated the root cause by excluding directories of Laravel. The bad directory was actually the `app/View` due too an early mistake I made by generating `laravel` `components` Laravel generates `view` and
`controller` files for a component. It's not always needed to touch the controller if you don't need php logic, which is why I did not see the issue.

I've created the components these times with a wrong pattern, which led Laravel to generate broken classes (my bad, not Laravel's). By cleaning those out, the coverage report was successfully generated without any exclusions.

Thanks to @hakre, I'm aware my issue was very generic and not really reproduceable.

Comment: Were you able to make phpunit be more verbose and pointing you to the file?

Comment: Not really. I simply went through the app structure and phpstorm highlighted the mentioned classes. That's how I found them.

Answer (score -1):

In case your wondering how he isolated.

Edit your phpunit.xml file

```
<coverage processUncoveredFiles="true">
    <include>
        <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>            
    </include>
    <exclude>
        <directory suffix=".php">./app/Http</directory>
        <!-- <file>src/example.php</file> -->
    </exclude>
</coverage>
```

Comment: This is incorrect. I isolated the root cause in the code.

Comment: yeah but how do you know where to look?

Comment: I went through the app structure and phpstorm highlighted the mentioned classes. That's how I found them.

Comment: That's no how others would want to do it

Comment: I agree. I'd also be happy if phpunit spot me to that ‍♂️.

Comment: excluding files or directories does not solve anything, it just hide the issue.

Comment: yes well that's how we isolate the issue